# How can I relate two systems of ODEs, when their initial conditions are related?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

Consider two simple ODEs with identical right-hand sides, whose initial conditions are related by a simple formula.

$$x' = a \cdot x, \quad y' = a \cdot y, \quad x(0) = \alpha \cdot y (0)$$

The solutions to these are

$$y(t) = y(0)\exp(c \cdot t)$$

$$x(t) = x(0)\exp(c \cdot t) = \frac{\alpha \cdot y(0)}{y(0)} y(t).$$

In particular, this allows us to solve for $x(t)$ only by knowing $y(t)$, without having to integrate the right-hand side of the ODE describing $x$.

I would like to extend this idea to systems of ODEs. For example, consider the systems

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix} x_1' \\ x_2' \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
\begin{bmatrix} y_1' \\ y_2' \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$

with initial conditions related by

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix} x_1(0) \\ x_2(0) \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} y_1 (0) \\ y_2(0) \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Is it possible to express the solution to $\vec{x}(t)$ in terms of   $\vec{y}(t)$, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, and $\delta$?

To preempt the obvious question, I need to solve many systems of this type with varying initial conditions, and would like to do the numerical integration only once.

Comment: For simple homogeneous D.E. you have the exact solution. Why need the numerical integration?

Comment: I have found it to be faster than calculating the matrix exponential when the system is large. Is there a better way? It's possible I'm doing something dumb.

Comment: Shouldn't the equation-3 be: $x(t)=\alpha y(0)y(t)$

Comment: I don't think so: I'm substituting $\exp(ct) = y(t) / y(0)$.

Comment: Then $x(t) = \alpha y(t)$. According to the equation, wouldn't $x$ be independent of its initial conditions?

Comment: You're right about the simplification, but I wanted to leave the dependence on $y(0)$ explicit to illustrate my question. As for the initial conditions, $x(t)$ depends on $y(t)$, which in turn depends on $y(0)$, which would change if we changed $x(0)$ due to the relation between $y(0)$ and $x(0)$. So, $x$ does depend on its initial conditions.

Comment: I think you can find $\vec{x}(t) = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha  ~ \beta \\ \gamma  ~ \delta \end{bmatrix}  \vec{y}(t)$ if notheing changes but the initial conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something similar will work.  You need to solve two ODEs
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix} x_1' \\ x_2' \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}
,\quad
\begin{bmatrix} y_1' \\ y_2' \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
with initial conditions
$$ \begin{bmatrix} x_1(0) \\ x_2(0)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad \begin{bmatrix} y_1(0) \\ y_2(0)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} .$$
Then the solution to
$$
\begin{bmatrix} z_1' \\ z_2' \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix}
$$
is
$$
\begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix}
= z_1(0) \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix} + 
 z_2(0) \begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\ y_2 \end{bmatrix} .$$

Comment: Also, this will work for non-homogeneous systems.  All you need is linearity.

Comment: Should it be $z_1(0) [x_1, x_2] + z_2(0) [y_1, y_2]$? If not, where did the $z(1)$ come from?

Comment: Yes, I fixed it.  Thanks.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Your answer is not being rendered correctly   in my browser (chrome). There is no issue with other posts.

Comment: @Galaxy If you go to my profile, it will give you a link to my webpage, which  has my email address.  If you send me an email, I'll return you a PDF of my answer rendered correctly.  (I also am using chrome.)

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Thank you, It is OK now.